# Google Analyctics Custom Variables - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, google-analytics

I need help outputting "First and last name" as custom variables in Google Analytics. I tried this but didn't work.

```
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'author', '<?php echo ucfirst($blogdata['User']['first_name'])." ".ucfirst($blogdata['User']['last_name']);?>',3]);
```

When checking source code/GA debugger, first and last name value is blank: `_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 1, 'author', ' ',3]);`

Here's how First and last name are displaying on my blog.

```
<?php $ud =  ucfirst($blogdata['User']['first_name'])." ".ucfirst($blogdata['User']['last_name']).'&nbsp;/&nbsp;'  ; ?>
          <?php $ud .= $blogdata['UserType']['type'].'&nbsp;/&nbsp;'; ?>
           <?php $ud .= 'On '. $this->Time->format('M j, Y', $blogdata['Blog']['publish_date']).''; ?>
        <?php echo 'Posted By: '.  $this->Html->link($ud, $profilepath, array('escape' => false, 'target' => '_blank')); ?>
```

Comment: I'm guessing `$blogdata` is set in the view, not the layout, which means it wouldn't be available to the layout. Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely because `$blogdata` is set in the view, and therefore not available in the layout which is where the analytics are usually placed.

To make it available to the layout, set the data in the `beforeFilter` callback on your App controller.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
  $blogdata = array(); // find data here
  $this->set('blogdata', $blogdata);
}
```